# Order enrollment records by date per student

Tags: sql, ms-access, ranking

I essentially have a table in MS Access that has student enrollment records like this:

> Student ID, Enrollment Date, Enrollment Code
>   12345, 8/25/2014, E01
>   12345, 9/5/2014, WD02
>   12345, 10/3/2014, E01
>   23456, 8/25/2014, E01
>   34567, 8/25/2014, E01
>   34567, 10/01/2014, WD03

The above basically would mean that student 12345 enrolled on 8/25, withdrew on 9/5, and re-enrolled on 10/3; Student 23456 enrolled on 8/25 and is still enrolled; Student 34567 enrolled on 8/25, withdrew on 10/1 and is still withdrawn.

I need to check the order of these records and make sure that we don't have two enrollment records without a withdraw in between and other similar logical errors, as that clearly doesn't make sense.

Here's the issue: I can't figure out for the life of me how to rank these records in Access! Here's what I would like to end up with:

> Student ID, Enrollment Date, Enrollment Code, Rank
>   12345, 8/25/2014, E01, 1
>   12345, 9/5/2014, WD02, 2
>   12345, 10/3/2014, E01, 3
>   23456, 8/25/2014, E01, 1
>   34567, 8/25/2014, E01, 1
>   34567, 10/01/2014, WD03, 2

So the rank should start over at every student. This way I can check that every record with a rank of an odd number is an E01 (since that is the only valid entry code) and that each even number is like "WD*", etc. It's not that hard to check right now because as of October we don't have that much movement, but as kiddos start transferring and coming in and out this starts to take hours to look at if you need to look at every student that has more than one record (what I'm currently doing).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The eventual goal is to automate this in a macro so that it just spits out any crazy records each week and we just fix and move on without having to review every kid that moved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You may have to change the field names/table name.

```
SELECT s.StudentID, s.EnrollmentDate, s.enrollmentcode,

(
SELECT Count(*)
FROM students AS t
WHERE t.enrollmentdate < students.enrollmentdate 
AND s.studentid = t.studentid
)+1 AS Test

FROM students AS s
ORDER BY s.StudentID, s.EnrollmentDate;
```

We basically just use the Enrollment Date as a means to order the records to help us build out the row number. (I don't think anyone can withdraw before they enroll.)